# Rundeck - Move Hyper-V VM throught Powershell

Tags: rundeck

I'm new to Rundeck.

I succeed to launch SSH commands on my linux servers, CMD and Powershell on my Windows VM or Host.

But !
But, I can't launch this kind of commands to move my MV from one host to another :

Command : Move-VM "SRV12-XXX" srv-hypervisor2 -IncludeStorage -DestinationStoragePath D:\Hyper-V\SRV12-XXX

I get this kind of error :

The remote commection fail with the following error message :
An error has occurred which Windows PowerShell cannot handle. A remote session might have ended.

Do you know how I can make it works ?

When I run the below command to know if I'm looged "as admin" an answer is true :
 (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)

Thanks in advance for you help.

Cédric

Comment: Did you try directly on the Windows machine to test? check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/powershell-direct (possible causes: 1) the virtual machine exists but is not running. 2) The guest OS does not support PowerShell Direct. 3) PowerShell isn't available in the guest yet -> a) The operating system hasn't finished booting, b) the operating system can't boot correctly or c) some boot time event needs user input)

Comment: Yes I did. Powershell Direct seems to be dedicated to commands from the host to the guest. I just want to launch this command on the host. Cédric

Comment: Commands like Get-VM works from rundeck. Not Move-VM.